# IstanbulJS code coverage shows 100% line coverage but <100% statement coverage

Tags: mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I am using Mocha for my test runner, and nyc for the test reporter. I don't see any uncovered lines and was wondering if anyone knows how can be uncovered functions and statements, while every line is covered. Ideas?

```
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File                |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
  file.js           |    98.77 |      100 |    88.89 |      100 |                |
```

Comment: Are you using typescript or pure JS?

Comment: Pure JS. It's running on node version 8.

Comment: Check the HTML report and find the branch not tested. Sometimes the text report is not totally accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Leonardo Venoso pointed me in the right direction on this.

Running

```
nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text npm test
```

gave me a file located in `./coverage` that highlighted the exact code that wasn't covered.

It was a line similar to

```js
let data = arr.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));
```

`(a,b) => a.compareTo(b)` was never called because `arr` had a length of 1.